# Appery.io API Express Timeout

Tags: timeout, appery.io

I have brought this up before. Being in South Africa, it is impossible to use API Express due to the fact that your max timeout is 10 000ms. This is hardly enough due to network latency between South Africa and America.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [pricing page](https://appery.io/pricing) you can select the Team plan to have such a timeout without influence to your project.
"Beginners" plan has 3 sec and "Pro" 5 sec, so it won't be enough for you